# Reference for a study material of exact solution of Helium atom in 3D?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, resource-recommendations

I am curious to read exact solution of [Helium atom](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=helium+atom+quantum+mechanics) in 3D. Can anyone refer me a reference, a book or a site?

Comment: Any elementary textbook will have this, and elementary searches will provide a large number of sites as well.

Comment: Hmm I updated the question!

Comment: The helium atom has no analytic solution. Any atom with more than one electron has interactions between the electrons that mean the wave equation has no analytic solution. Instead we have to use approximate methods like Hartree-Fock.

Comment: It is extremely rude to change your question (from hydrogen to helium) so much that it completely invalidates an existing answer. I have downvoted because of this, and have voted to close your question.

Comment: @G.Smith No problem sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to read the book:

Bransden, B. H., Joachain, C. J., & Plivier, T. J. (2003). Physics of atoms and molecules. Pearson education.

Chapter VII has a good description of two electron-atoms properties, with analytic results.
Even though a detailed analysis is provided, an exact analytical solution is missing. That's because, as far as I know, an exact analytical solution is still missing. Same for:

Cohen-Tannoudji, C., Diu, B., Laloe, F., & Dui, B. (2006). Quantum Mechanics (2 vol. set).
In this case, see chapter 14.

I also heard of:

Drake, G. W. (Ed.). (2006). Springer handbook of atomic, molecular, and optical physics. Springer Science & Business Media,

but never read it.

Comment: Hey I changed the question, you can delete this answer or update it to help me!

Comment: Changed, hope it gets useful

Comment: Thank you very much sir!